# Error Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Unable to retrieve service key for ServicePrincipal account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

Using PowerShell, I can access my Azure KeyVault locally, provide the secret and return stored passwords. I can also do this from a VM I spin up. Additionally, I can access a single password from the KeyVault and use it to impersonate a user on a VSTS build agent, but I cannot access the remaining stored passwords. What gives?

Here's the message I receive:

> [error]Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Unable to retrieve service key for
> ServicePrincipal account
> [hiddenaccountname]@[companyaccount].com. Please log in
> again to supply the credentials for this service  principal. In
> PowerShell, execute Login-AzureRMAccount for Azure Resource Manager
> cmdlets or Add-AzureAccount for  service management cmdlets.
>
> ...
>
> - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret], KeyNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.GetAzureKeyVaultSecret

Here's what my code looks like at this section:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCredential -ServicePrincipal -TenantId [abunchofnumbers]

$Password  = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "[nameOfVault]" -Name "[nameOfSecret]").SecretValueText
```

The login accepts the provided credentials and logs me in, but the Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret cmdlet fails, and only on VSTS during a build.

Any ideas, you strange and wonderful devs?

Comment: Do you add the service principal in key vault access policy?

Comment: Try to call Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret through Azure PowerShell task and check the result. This issue may benefit you: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3389

Comment: @ShengbaoShui, yes. Thanks for checking. And Get and List are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resolved - Follow up] My process involved one Powershell script to impersonate a user by using Login-AzureRmAccount and Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret to get the password for a user, then a 2nd Powershell script to log back in to AzureRmAccount to get more passwords from the KeyVault. I swapped the order of these two scripts and problem went away.